# Query with OR condition through an association

Tags: mysql, sql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I'm trying to facilitate finding a user record via either username or email. THe only issue is that the username is stored on an associated `UserDetail` model.

```
class User
  has_one :user_detail

  def self.find_by_username_or_email(value)

    # This is effectively pseudocode for the query I'd like to write.
    query = "lower(email) = :value OR user_detail.username = :value"
    where([query, { value: value }]).first
  end
end
```

How can I write a query which matches either the email or the username on the associated `user_detail` record?

Comment: Calm down Yoshiji :-) I'll have a proper look in the morning when I'm back in work. If it helps you'll get your rewards!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were almost there!

This should work for you:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :user_detail

  def self.find_by_username_or_email(value)
    query = "lower(users.email) = :value OR user_details.username = :value"
    includes(:user_detail).where(query, value: value).first
  end
end
```

Comment: This query is taking way too long to run. On the order of minutes with a users table with about 27k rows. Any suggestions for making it faster?

Comment: Got the speed problems fixed. This is much faster: `joins(:user_detail).where(query, value: value).first` because it uses `INNER JOIN` instead of `LEFT OUTER JOIN`.

Answer (score 1):

seems like you need to write

```
self.includes(:user_detail).where(" user.email = ? OR user_detail.user_name =?", param[1], param[2])
```

Comment: You need to use `includes(:user_detail)` (singular) because the relation is declared as `has_one :user_detail` (singular).